Docker Ubuntu: Unable to Stream from Ethernet Camera
Background:
Hello all. I am attempting to solve a problem by placing complex systems within Docker containers. The platform hosting these containers has 6+ ethernet ports on NIC cards which are used in a variety of ways (cameras connected to two ports, a system LAN connected to another port, etc.).
On the system LAN, I need to assign each Docker container its own IP address on the LAN’s subnet. The IP addresses of the cameras are on a different subnet and persisted directly on the cameras themselves.
What I Have Done:
In order to assign static IP addresses to the containers on the system LAN, I implemented that network with a MACVLAN driver and fussed with the routing table on the host. This works as expected, providing access to other platforms on the system LAN.
In order to be able to access the cameras from the containers, I implemented that network with an IPVLAN driver. This solution provides limited access to the cameras. More on this shortly. I started out attempting to use the MACVLAN driver for the cameras, but had no access to the camera’s IP addresses within the containers.
Just for grins, I made the network_mode be host on the container and commented out all my other network implementations. Everything seems to work like a charm inside the container. Of course this will not work for my situation because I still need to assign a static IP address to the container (system architectural constraint).
I suspect that either my Docker network configuration, my host routing table, my firewall, or all are not quite right.
Docker Image:
A nearly bare-bones Ubuntu:20.04 image with inetutils-ping, iproute2, iputiles-ping, and net-tools installed.
docker-compose file:
Version: '3.1'

services:
  my_container:
    container_name: pc1-a
    hostname:       pc1-a
    image:          my-image
    privileged:     true
    stdin_open:     true
    tty:            true
    command:        /bin/bash
#    network_mode:   host
    networks:
      system_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.127.102
      cam1_net:

    ports:
      - "8022:22"

networks:
  system_net:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth6
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet:  192.168.127.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.127.1
          ip_range: 192.168.127.96/28
          aux_addresses:
            host: 192.168.127.101

  cam1_net:
    driver: ipvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth1
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet:   192.168.11.0/24
          gateway:  192.168.11.1
          ip_range: 192.168.11.0/28
          aux_addresses:
            dev:  192.168.11.11
            host: 192.168.11.10

(If I uncomment the network_mode line above, I need to comment the networks information following.)
With the above configuration, ifconfig on the host yields:
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 192.168.11.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.11.255
                inet6 fe80::fa02:78ff:fe22:16d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
                        ether f8:02:78:22:16:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
                                RX packets 194707  bytes 1735032084 (1.7 GB)
                                        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
                                                ...

Inside the container, ifconfig yields:
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 192.168.11.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.11.255
                inet6 fe80::f802:7800:122:16d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
                        ether f8:02:78:22:16:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
                                RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
                                        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
                                                ...

Note that Docker renamed eth1 on the host to eth0 within the container. Note also that no packets are being received inside the container.
Although it is too cumbersome to show here, I did install the Pleora camera SDK in the container and ran some of its sample utilities. These utilities worked perfectly when the network-mode was host, but timed out with the above network configuration.
